# Is there a way to isolate 'localStorage' between different tabs?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am currently using window.localStorage to store some client side data on browser. But I'd like to isolate this storage to individual tabs.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: localStorage is by domain. Only thing would could do is create a unique name for the tab and use that as the start of the key for localstorage.

Comment: What is "tab"? If you refresh a page - is it still the same "tab" or not?

Comment: I think you should explain your use case better, more than just "I want to store data per tab". Why do you need it? What are you trying to build?

Answer (score 4):

You should consider using **[sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)** instead:

> sessionStorage is similar to localStorage; the only difference is while data stored in localStorage has no expiration time, data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends. A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores. Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated with the value of the top-level browsing context [...]

Comment: idk does not work for me, `sessionStorage.getItem` returns `null` in next tab

Comment: You seem to have misread both the question and my answer. The asker *wants* storage to be isolated between tabs, which is what `sessionStorage` provides. It sounds like you need `localStorage` which is shared instead of isolated.