# Updating LocalStorage with the same data in the same time on multiple tabs causing problems

Tags: javascript, vue.js, websocket, frontend, local-storage

first of all i'm a beginer front end developer and i'm not a native english speaker so sorry for any mistake i made in my first question :D I'm working on project in Vue that was started by someone else. It uses websocket to display some notifications from server and i spotted a bug associated with this. The notifications are stored in object that pulls data from localStorage using VueUse's useStorage:

```
const state = reactive({
  liveNotifications: useStorage("liveNotifications", []),
  notificationsCount: 0,
});
```

And when data is received from ws it's being added to the beginning of the array like this:

```
connections.alerts.onmessage = (event) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(event.data);

    if (data?.status) {
      return;
    }

    state.liveNotifications.unshift(data);
    state.notificationsCount += 1;
  };
```

The problem is, when more than 2 tabs are opened and ws send some notifications, the localstorage starts acting weird like its trying to add the same objects over and over and notificationsCount is jumping (for example) from 2 to 3 and vice versa.
Is there any way to e.g. prevent app from updating localstorage multiple times if the data given from ws is the same on all tabs. Or maybe there's another way to make this work properly?

I've tried some solutions from web but to be honest i'm not really sure why is this happening and i didn't know what exactly i was supposed to look for so if someone has better knowledge than me and can help me understand i'm here to learn :)

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you find a good solution?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is: both tabs will read/write to the same "file".

> The localStorage read-only property of the window interface allows you to access a Storage object for the Document's origin; the stored data is saved across browser sessions.
>
> [MDN - Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56349852/is-there-a-way-to-isolate-localstorage-between-different-tabs) is to use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) instead:

> [...] the difference is that while data in localStorage doesn't expire, data in sessionStorage is cleared when the page session ends.
>
> - Whenever a document is loaded in a particular tab in the browser, a unique page session gets created and assigned to that particular tab. That page session is valid only for that particular tab.

Comment: The problem in this case is that the notifications should stay in storage until the user submits it so sessionStorage isn't really what im looking for since all the notifications will be lost after closing the tab :(

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a [shared worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers#shared_workers).

Since you are receiving the same data it is reduntant to keep two connections.

You should handle your websocket connection in a shared worker, then upon receiving the data save it to the localStorage, then post a message to the tabs to update the UI.